# Is it okay to use the present simple in this case?

Tags: present-simple

There’s the snow. This snow didn’t melt, isn’t melting and will never melt. Then, is ‘the snow melts if the air temperature is above 32°F’ a valid sentence?

Comment: If the snow will never melt, then the temperature of the air is irrelevant, so the sentence is ***grammatical***, but ***false***.

Comment: It is a valid sentence, but we need more information to understand what you want it to mean or what you think it means. Do you mean all snow, or a specific piece or ball of snow? Do you know or believe that the temperature will increase? Do you know that it won’t? Or do you mean that all snow always melts when it’s warm enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

We usually use the present simple to talk about things that are always or generally true or claimed:

> The world is round.

> Dogs chase cats.

You probably don’t want to use “the” to introduce snow if you are talking about snow in general.

Comment: Sir, is also a plain sentence without modification like ‘the snow melts” true even though the snow didn’t and won’t melt?

Comment: That's an optimistic statement in today's world! Are you referring to a particular patch of snow rather than snow in general?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes, a particular patch of snow.

Comment: The snow _would melt_ if the temperature _were to rise_ above 32 degrees F.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes, but I also want to know just ‘snow melts’ is true even though the snow didn’t and won’t melt.

Comment: That's exactly why I asked whether you were referring to a particular patch of snow! Snow [in general] melts at warmer temperatures. If you say that _your_ snow won't melt, it must be constantly below freezing point, so it's not true that _this_ snow melts.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you.

Comment: @Kate Bunting You know, the present simple tense is a timeless tense. Does that mean ‘the snow melts’ is true even if the snow won’t melt but it did melt previously?

Comment: If a given area of snow melted in the past, it became water and either ran away or re-froze into ice, so your question makes no sense.

Comment: @Kate Bunting It evaporated into the sky and It became snow again. :)

Comment: Ah. You are talking about a particular patch or lump of snow. You are not sure if the air will get warmer than 32C? If you aren’t sure, then James K’s answer is right. I think you should edit the question to better describe the situation you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In a hypothetical construction you would use the "second conditional"

> The snow would melt if the air temperature was above 32F.

This means that you think it is unlikely that the temperature will be above 32F.  The use of the past tense in this context doesn't relate to events in the past.